# SpellCheck in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, spell-checking

Is there any way I can add words to the Spell check dictionary through code lotus script.
I have used spell check in the form for validation of content, but there are few keywords which are system codes or html codes and will always be a part of the content.
I need to add those keywords to the spell check dictionary before the spell check uidoc.spellcheck() is called.

This is required to be done from backend because we cannot ask thousands of users using the db to sit with the list and add themselves. And its a pain to skip all these list of words everytime the form is validated.

I have also coded to read and write xml files to match the exact format as in default "Dictionary.xml" file. But, it doesn't seem to be taking from that file.However, it just gets those words that I add through "AddToDictionary" button when spell check is triggered.Is there anywhere else, that these words are stored?

Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: which version of Lotus Notes?

Comment: it is lotus notes 8.5

Answer (score 1):

Words added to your custom dictionary are stored in the userDictionary.xml file located here :

[Notes data dir]\workspace\UDM\UserDictionary.xml.

It's pretty simple to parse XML with the new(ish) Notes XML classes, so I can't think of reason why you shouldn't be able to modify this file.

Nick.